# Problems multicast receive TCP packets

Tags: sockets, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I create a network device, with the possibility of multicasting dev->flags = IFF_MULTICAST.

If I send a UDP message. That works fine, I receive the message in the other socket correctly. I define two sockets as:

```
sockEnvio = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);  

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));    
server.sin6_family = AF_INET6;    
server.sin6_scope_id = if_nametoindex("eth2");    
server.sin6_port = htons(15118);    
bind(sockEnvio, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));  

int optval = 1;    
setsockopt(sockEnvio, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_RECVPKTINFO, &optval, sizeof(optval));

optval = 0;        
setsockopt(sockEnvio, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, &optval, sizeof(optval));

struct ipv6_mreq mreq;    
memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(mreq));    
mreq.ipv6mr_interface = if_nametoindex("eth2");    
mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr.s6_addr[ 0] = 0xff;    
mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr.s6_addr[ 1] = 0x02;    
mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr.s6_addr[15] = 0x02;    
setsockopt(sockEnvio, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq))
```

But if I send a TCP message throw the client, when I receive a packet on the server, I don´t receive a tcp message. I define client as:

```
sockTCP = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM,0))

memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
client.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
client.sin6_scope_id = if_nametoindex("eth2");
client.sin6_port = htons(50118); 
inet_pton(AF_INET6,"fe80:0000:0000:0000:02b0:52ff:feff:ff02",(void*)&client.sin6_addr.s6_addr);

bind(sockTCP, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(client));

struct hostent *hp;
hp = gethostbyname2("fe80::a2b0:c0ff:fed0:e0f0",AF_INET6);
if (hp == NULL) {
   printf("ERROR, no such host  \n");
}

memset(&from2, 0, sizeof(from2));
from2.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
from2.sin6_port = htons(50117); 
inet_pton(AF_INET6,"fe80::a2b0:c0ff:fed0:e0f0",(void*)&from2.sin6_addr.s6_addr);

int optval = 1;
setsockopt(sockTCP, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_RECVPKTINFO, &optval, sizeof(optval));
optval = 0;
setsockopt(sockTCP, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, &optval, sizeof(optval));

connect(sockTCP, (struct sockaddr *)&from2, sizeof(from2));
```

I define the server socket as:

```
sockEnvioTCP = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM,0))

memset(&server, 0, sizeof(server));    
server.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
server.sin6_scope_id = if_nametoindex("eth2");
server.sin6_port = htons(50117);
server.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;

int optval = 1;
setsockopt(sockEnvioTCP, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_RECVPKTINFO, &optval, sizeof(optval));    
optval = 0;
setsockopt(sockEnvioTCP, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP, &optval, sizeof(optval));

bind(sockTCP, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));

listen(sockTCP, 5);
accept(sockTCP, (struct sockaddr *) &from, sizeof(from));
```

The system trace at the server is:

```
ipv6_rcv()
    |--> ip6_route_input()
          |-->ip6_mc_input()
              |-->icmpv6_rcv()
```

In the client the gethostbyname2(...) is not NULL.

In the server the type of the ICMP message is 135 (Neighbor Solicitation). The destination address is "ff2:00:00:00:00:01:ffd0:e0f0".The value returned by ipv6_chk_mcast_addr() in function ip6_mc_input() is some times 1 and others 0.

At UDP socket I have to join the destination multicast group. But how do I make it in a TCP socket?

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: TCP and multicast are mutually exclusive. Not possible. Not even a bit.

Comment: Ok, Then what is the problem?, Why I send I message and the socket send a ICMP message?.

Comment: Well, you _cannot_ send a message with TCP via multicast. You simply can't, it doesn't matter what you're doing. Not only is TCP a stream protocol which does not have a concept of "message", but also TCP requires precise 1-to-1, end-to-end connection establishment and does per-connection rate limiting and reliable in-order transport, which is mutually exclusive with multicasting.

Comment: If you had written proper error checking into your code you would have discovered for yourself that setting the multicast socket option on a TCP socket had failed. Don't write code like this.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a pure end to end protocol and does not support multicast.
Now you may wonder why this is the case ?
Well TCP is constantly sending ack's from one peer to the other peer to confirm the bytes that it has received properly, because it is a streaming protocol. If such a confirmation does not arrive, then TCP will retransmit, several times if need be.
Now suppose it were multicast, then TCP would need to monitor the receipt acknowledgments of several others. If you think about that for a minute, knowing that TCP is already quite complex, you might realize why it is not supported.